# An unseen Error while importing camelot package on databricks

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-import, azure-databricks, python-camelot

I am trying to import camelot package on databricks and I am facing the attached error for the first time. The same script worked fine till 9th August 2023. But now I am getting this TypeError. I tried searching for solution but couldn't get any thing that I can use. If someone has seen this before while working on camelot then please help.

**ERROR LOG :
**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-1234471206721195>:5
      3 import re
      4 import time
----> 5 import camelot
      6 import requests
      7 import smtplib

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PythonPackageImportsInstrumentation/__init__.py:171, in _create_import_patch.<locals>.import_patch(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1
    168 try:
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information.
--> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import.

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/__init__.py:6
      3 import logging
      5 from .__version__ import __version__
----> 6 from .io import read_pdf
      7 from .plotting import PlotMethods
     10 # set up logging

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PythonPackageImportsInstrumentation/__init__.py:171, in _create_import_patch.<locals>.import_patch(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1
    168 try:
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information.
--> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import.

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/io.py:5
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      3 import warnings
----> 5 from .handlers import PDFHandler
      6 from .utils import validate_input, remove_extra
      9 def read_pdf(
     10     filepath,
     11     pages="1",
   (...)
     16     **kwargs
     17 ):

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PythonPackageImportsInstrumentation/__init__.py:171, in _create_import_patch.<locals>.import_patch(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1
    168 try:
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information.
--> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import.

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/handlers.py:9
      6 from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
      8 from .core import TableList
----> 9 from .parsers import Stream, Lattice
     10 from .utils import (
     11     TemporaryDirectory,
     12     get_page_layout,
   (...)
     16     download_url,
     17 )
     20 class PDFHandler(object):

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PythonPackageImportsInstrumentation/__init__.py:171, in _create_import_patch.<locals>.import_patch(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1
    168 try:
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information.
--> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import.

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/parsers/__init__.py:4
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      3 from .stream import Stream
----> 4 from .lattice import Lattice

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PythonPackageImportsInstrumentation/__init__.py:171, in _create_import_patch.<locals>.import_patch(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1
    168 try:
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information.
--> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import.

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/parsers/lattice.py:25
     14 from ..core import Table
     15 from ..utils import (
     16     scale_image,
     17     scale_pdf,
   (...)
     23     compute_whitespace,
     24 )
---> 25 from ..image_processing import (
     26     adaptive_threshold,
     27     find_lines,
     28     find_contours,
     29     find_joints,
     30 )
     31 from ..backends.image_conversion import BACKENDS
     34 logger = logging.getLogger("camelot")

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PythonPackageImportsInstrumentation/__init__.py:171, in _create_import_patch.<locals>.import_patch(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1
    168 try:
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information.
--> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import.

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/image_processing.py:3
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
----> 3 import cv2
      4 import numpy as np
      7 def adaptive_threshold(imagename, process_background=False, blocksize=15, c=-2):

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PythonPackageImportsInstrumentation/__init__.py:171, in _create_import_patch.<locals>.import_patch(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1
    168 try:
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information.
--> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import.

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:664, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:627, in _load_backward_compatible(spec)

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/PostImportHook.py:218, in _ImportHookChainedLoader.load_module(self, fullname)
    216 def load_module(self, fullname):
    217     try:
--> 218         module = self.loader.load_module(fullname)
    219         notify_module_loaded(module)
    220     except (ImportError, AttributeError):

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:181
    176             if DEBUG: print("Extra Python code for", submodule, "is loaded")
    178     if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: DONE')
--> 181 bootstrap()

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:175, in bootstrap()
    172 if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: binary extension... OK')
    174 for submodule in __collect_extra_submodules(DEBUG):
--> 175     if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
    176         if DEBUG: print("Extra Python code for", submodule, "is loaded")
    178 if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: DONE')

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module(base, name, enable_debug_print)
     26 native_module = sys.modules.pop(module_name, None)
     27 try:
---> 28     py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
     29 except ImportError as err:
     30     if enable_debug_print:

File /usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127, in import_module(name, package)
    125             break
    126         level += 1
--> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7f856e60-6cd1-4854-8503-cef3ccc841c4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/typing/__init__.py:69
     65 import typing
     68 if numpy.lib.NumpyVersion(numpy.__version__) > "1.20.0" and sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
---> 69     NumPyArrayGeneric = numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.generic]]
     70 else:
     71     NumPyArrayGeneric = numpy.ndarray

TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

I was trying to import the python package and I was expecting 'import camelot' to be imported properly

Answer (score 0):

Even, I got the same error as you.

[image]

This is because of  incompatible `NumPy` versions.
Upgrade the NumPy to latest or install below one.

```
pip install numpy==1.22.4
```

And got imported successfully.

```
import camelot; print('Camelot', camelot.__version__)
```

[image]